# Javascript RegEx for HH:mm string

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have 5 time ranges I need to create a regular expression for

1) < 18:00

2) >= 18:00 < 20:00

3) >= 20:00 < 24:00

4) >= 24:00 < 30:00

5) > 30:00

My string data is in string format "HH:mm"
So as an e.g. 7AM would be 07:00 4:30PM would be 16:30

I've created the RegEx but cannot seem to figure out why they are not working

```
*PRINT 'var regExCat1 = "^(0[0-9]|1[0-7]+):([0-5]?[0-9]+)$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat2 = "^(|1[8-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9]+)$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat3 = "^(2[0-3]+):([0-5]?[0-9]+)$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat4 = "^(2[4-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9]+)$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat5 = "^([3-9]?[0-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9]+)$";'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Test them at regex101.com and debug them? Also did you know that `+` means match the previous token one or more times?

Comment: Sorry I was comparing my RegEx on a wrong column...doh...It is working (somewhat, I just need to fix up a couple of the expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var regExCat1 = "^(0[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]|1[0-7]:[0-5]?[0-9])$";'

var regExCat2 = "^(1[8-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])$";'

var regExCat3 = "^(2[0-3]:[0-5]?[0-9])$";'

var regExCat4 = "^(2[4-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])$";'

var regExCat5 = "^([3-9]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])$";'

Comment: in case somebody comes across this question

Answer (score 0):

You have quantifiers where you don't need them. See the changes below:

```
*PRINT 'var regExCat1 = "^(0[0-9]|1[0-7]):([0-5][0-9])$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat2 = "^(1[8-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat3 = "^(2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat4 = "^(2[4-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";'
*PRINT 'var regExCat5 = "^([3-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";'
```